# unable to open window tabwidget using qgis python plugin

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have created a window using pyqt4 designer and converted the UI to a python file using puuic4. I added some code to open this window using the qgis python plugin but I get the following error:

```
tabwidget does not have attribute addTab
```

I'm using the following code for the GUI:

```
class Ui_TabWidget(QDialog):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        TabWidget.show()

    def setupUi(self, TabWidget):
        ...
```

For the python plugin in qgis I used following code:

```
setG=Ui_TabWidget(self.iface.mainWindow())
setG.exec_()
```

Comment: Check my writeup on the subject: http://mlgsoft.com/wp/?p=11